# Diagnostics.Process.Start doesn't open browser

Tags: c#, iis, reporting-services, .net-4.5, windows-server-2012

In an ASP.NET Web App, I am simply trying to open a report in SSRS that is on a different server than the website.

```
Diagnostics.Process.Start(String.Format("http://Trumpdb1/ReportServer?/prod/ShipmentPackingSlip&rs:Command=Render&ShipmentID={0}", shipmentid))
```

I can't find an error thrown anywhere but nothing seems to happen. The Try/Catch doesn't catch an error. There is no cross domain error or anything. If I paste the real url for the report into a browser it works.

However when I debug the web app in VS2017 with either Chrome or IE it works opening the report in a new browser tab.

Comment: If you replace the URL with something "stupid" like `"http://www.google.com"`, does it open Google in the browser? Just trying to make sure the very basic scenario works.

Comment: You are running this in an ASP Web app, what do you expect to happen? Are you wanting to open the report in a new window? You are starting a process on the server, the user doesn't have access to that.

Comment: @RonBeyer That makes sense. I'll have to change the button to be ajax.

Comment: Generally speaking, any process you try to start inside ASP.NET running on IIS will launch as a "headless" process on the server, if it's able to launch at all.

Comment: The browser is opened, but you simply cannot see it, https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3

Comment: I monitored the process via process monitor. It seems that when you execute process.start in IIS express. Worker process and your desktop application run in the same session. So web browser can be activated.  However, when you host it in IIS, w3wp.exe are placed in session 0. That's why its not working.